# bifurcation diagram of SI model in geogebra

Tags: bifurcation

I want to plot $I$ against $R_0$ in Geogebra (bifurcation diagram), these are related by the following system

$\begin{cases}S^\prime(t,S,I)=\frac{A}{b}-\frac{R_0SI}{S+I}-S\\I^\prime(t,S,I)=\frac{R_0SI}{S+I}-I\end{cases}$

where $R_0=\beta/b$. So, what I did was give initial conditions of $S,I$ and $t$, and assigned some values to A and b, then I used the Nsolve function to solve the system for $s$ and $I$.

Now plotting $I$ against $R_0$ gives me an error when I try to iterate $I$ to get some points.

Comment: How do I attach screen shot of what I have?

Comment: I think you need a certain level of reputation to include images, but, if it's something that you can do, then there'll be a button (looking like a mountain range against a black background) in the post editor that allows you to insert an image.  However, MO is not usually for software questions, so this question will probably be closed.  Wherever you ask this, you will want to include more detail of exactly what you did, and exactly what the error message was.